# Doubts about Max232 IC chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, serial, rs232, max232, db9

I have a Max 202 Ic and Max 232 Ic

I currently want to make a USB to RS232 Serial Db9 converter

i have the db9 male port, a max 232 and max 202 , usb female port and bunch of other passive components .

Is it possible to make a USB to DB9 Rs232 converter ? if yes , how ( any schematics ) ?

PS : also what is an alternative IC circuit to make USB to RS232 db9 ,  if this is not possible , ( i have this for my college project )

image : this is the project flow , as u can see at starting I need to make a USB to rs232 male DB 9 converter and this thread is about that

[image]

Comment: Check FTDI ICs e.g. FT232.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I have checked the FTDI IC , but its in SOC pin out , Any ICs in DIP config ?

Comment: Why do you need a `MAX232` chip if all voltage levels are below 5V? I thought `232` chips are for shifting the voltage levels and inverting the polarity to match the 12-15V RS232 output of PC to 5V output of the micro controller. And what's with the `SPI` block in the diagram?

Comment: @AJN actually according to the flowchart of my project - the first section  , i want to make a USB to RS232 DB9 male converter, i thought a max232 can help me do that , correct me if i am wrong , what should i use ( DIP IC ) to make the USB to RS232 DB 9 male converter?

Comment: I am not familiar with any DIP IC. But you can see if non DIP IC with [breakout board](https://www.google.com/search?q=ftdi+breakout+board) is available. The ic will come pre soldered to a PCB which will have pins that are consistent with DIP. But then, if you use such a board, you will need to expand the scope of your project since the board will solve most of the conversion work for you.

Comment: @swagdevotee008 The USB part is difficult if you are doing it entirely by yourself. Most small-fries (like me) who can't spend a year studying more than 1000 pages of USB specifications instead chooses a specialized IC. These come from a few (not many) sources. They are boutique ICs. But they work pretty well and they handle all the complicated stuff for you, including triggering O/S drivers for virtual COM ports. Really nice. Companies like TI don't do that. They just take one of their CPUs, write code for it, and are done. But most of us don't have the horsepower.

Comment: @swagdevotee008 So we use the boutique ICs, instead. They only use 3.3 V or 5.0 V rails. So although the protocol is straight from the RS-232 specification, the analog signaling is ***not***. So the MAX232 and its ilk (or back in my day, the MC1488 and MC1489, which I definitely do ***not*** recommend now) are used to covert from "logic level values" to the RS-232 specification values. The RS-232 MARK is anything from -3 V to -15 V and requires tolerance to -25 V. The RS-232 SPACE is anything from +3 V to +15 V and requires tolerance to +25 V.

Comment: @swagdevotee008 Some RS-232 receivers are fake. (See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/339565/38098) for details.) These pseudo-RS-232 end-points require that "the other side" be a ***real*** RS-232 driver and leach from its negative rail to create, temporarily, a negative rail they can use to reply. Some people imagine they don't have to generate the negative rail voltage in their RS-232 interface. But in these cases, they will fail to communicate properly. Just be aware.

Comment: The actual Rx threshold is the same for TTL 1.3V but RS-232 is bipolar for more noise and ringing margin. Good luck with USB code.

Comment: @swagdevotee008 In RS-232, everything between -3 V and +3 V is an illegal analog state. Signaling with a magnitude voltage that is more than 25 V is also outside the spec. Also, the receiver load must appear to a driver to be between 3 k and 7 k. Not below, nor above.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 actually sir , I want to make a usb to rs232 db9 convertor which is detectable by my PC using driver - as given above some users have told to use FTDI chips - FT232r / ft232h etc. - so i dont think so i would have to code . Any suggestion sir as to how i can make this usb to rs232 db9 circuit ( IC only in dip packaging ) ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=usb+to+rs232+schematic+driver&sxsrf=ALeKk02GFefY4mBkIp3NlZGZhgnkQslQ0A:1622356348662&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDkPGu5PDwAhWQZM0KHRQtDGwQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1293&bih=852  Seek and you shall find schematic and driver code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serial AVR programming and doubts](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/565618/serial-avr-programming-and-doubts)

Comment: You've asked this three or four times now. No, a UART is not the same as USB.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, no, you can't make a USB to serial adapter with simply onnectors and TTL-to-RS232 tranceiver chips. And most likely no DIP chips exist unless you build a software bit-bang implementation with a DIP MCU, which I also don't recommend.

But you don't have to maka a USB serial port yourself. You can just buy a ready made cable that contains all the electronics to have a USB-to-RS232 adapter.

But if you intend to serially bitbang SPI you can also buy an USB-to-TTL level adapter that has no RS232 transceiver so the TTL levels are suitable to direct connection to TTL level MCU, and you don't need MAX202 or MAX232 transceivers.

These devices exist as DIP modules as well.